# Firefox: modify bookmark dialog

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarks, css

When I want to add a bookmark in Firefox, I click on the star icon in the URL bar (bookmark this page), which brings up this pathetic bookmark window:

[image]

The window is extremely small, which makes navigation tedious. Also, it always preselects the "Other Bookmarks" as default location to store the bookmark. And the window has no resize button. Whatever evil person designed this, clearly wanted to make the experience as unpleasant as possible.

I would like to ask, if it is possible to:

1. make the bookmark window permanently bigger
2. instead of "Other Bookmarks" preselected, have the "Choose" option preselected, so that I can go straigt to my bookmark hierarchy tree to save, instead of having to switch to "Choose" each time.
3. disable/hide the "Tags" part of the bookmark. I have no idea what that is for, and I don't use it.

Perhaps some of these changes could be achieved by editing the `userChrome.css` or `userContent.css` files in Firefox profile?

I am using Firefox ESR 78.12

Comment: I have not tested but this link could be useful https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1242670

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio - thanks, but this has no effect.

Comment: If you can't find a suitable Add-On you can write your own. Also, FireFox is open source. If you can modify the source code to be better you could then issue a pull request to get your patch included in the official version.

Comment: I think without recompiling FF you can't do much.

Answer (score 2):

You might prefer the
[Default Bookmark Folder add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/default-bookmark-folder/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search).

This add-on is described as:

> Allows you to choose the default bookmark location folder and quickly bookmark pages via a dedicated icon.

But it can do many more functions.

[image]

Comment: There are options available which can be changed (or added/enabled) in `about:config`